# Extract field from object with destructuring assignment without creating variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

Instead of using 2 lines to deconstruct and print as follows:

```js
    const { field } = object;
    console.log(field);
```

I want to do this on one line through deconstruction without declaring a field where the outcome is the same as:

```js
    console.log(object.field)
```

Comment: The whole point of destructuring assignment is to create variables. If you don't want to create variables, then destructuring is not the right tool.

Comment: Why would you not just `object.field`? What's the purpose?

Comment: Eslint airbnb requires you do use deconstruction

Comment: Does it throw an error when you do it in 2 lines as well?

Comment: @KnutOlaNøsen Try: `console.log(object.field); // eslint-disable-line prefer-destructuring`

Comment: I can do it in 2 lines this is just some extra syntax optimization and i prefer keeping as few variables in scope as possible

Comment: You either remove the rule or you keep it in 2 lines. You can't put variable declarations in console log